# Solution for implementing Facebook-like notification

Tags: asp.net-web-api, unity-game-engine, notifications

I'm having a system which contains a Unity scene( social network view), which is connected to a DLL file written in C#, and this file is responsible for connect to WebAPIs hosted by ASP.NET WebAPI, which is the social network service. 
I'm trying to implement facebook-like notification service. What is the possible solutions/technique here to implement this feature?
I just read some example likes socket.io or SignalR but it seems that those things don't support C# client( the DLL) as well as ASP.Net WebAPI

Comment: I'm using signalr.  the client side is a simple html file with JavaScript.  the server side is a winform written in C# and inside this winform I called functions in dll written by another C# or vb.

Comment: Do you use SignalR with Asp.net API? How to set up to make 2 of them work perfectly together

Answer (score 0):

My app. is something like a Whatsapp chat app. plus e-bay online shopping.  It is mainly consist of 1 solution with 3 projects using Visual Studio 2015 Community RC.

project 1 is a JavaScript Cordova project with one and only one index.html file which is hosted in IIS 8.0 and is also capable of hosted as a native app. of an Android phone or iPhone.  So the clients can use any pc desktop browser, or mobile browser to use the app.  Or can install the app. from app stores of Android or iPhone.

project 2 is a Visual Basic Web Services hosted in IIS which contains all the backend business logic and connect to the ms sql server.

project 3 is a C# Signalr Server Winform, which can notify the clients if there is any new message.

for example, client X send a message to client Y:

1. index.html of X call VB Webservices to store the message in sql.
2. index.html of X call Signalr Server.
3. Signalr Server call Index.html of Y to notify there is a new message.
4. index.html of Y call VB Webservices to read the message.

You may wonder why I don't simply use signalr to send the message to Y, as the message is complicated, it can be a text or text with images or product information with product images.

As stated the index.html can be hosted inside the phone as native app, I also need to enable Cors in the webservices as well as the signalr.

of course the signalr Server can also call the VB webservices directly if needed.

Comment: Why don't you let the VB Webservices call SignalR Server to notify Y ?

Comment: because VB is the backend, I already reference VB inside the signalr, which means that when I build signalr, VB will be built automatically.

Comment: and in the real case there may have 2 X and 2 Y, each one of them Login using a pc desktop browser, at the same time login using mobile phone, suppose X send message thru pc, all other 3 devices receive the message

Comment: so, when x of pc send message thru signalr, the connection id of this 'x of pc' is known to the signalr server, so that the signalr Server should only send messages to 'x of mobile', 'y of pc' and 'y of mobile'.  if sent thru webservices, the connection id of 'x of pc', which is a random number, will not be known by the signalr server.

Comment: Okay I got it!
What about authorization? With WebAPI I can read the username of current logged in user
So how to do these same things with SignalR?

Comment: I do the login separately.  Signalr connection is established when the user open the app in the mobile phone, then user see my login screen and input user id and password.  then after using VB webservices to verify the encrpyted password, i connect the signalr Server to store the login id in pair with the connection id using an array or an arraylist.